# Redux state not changing in MUI switch button

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am using react redux-thunk. I have a set of users data that I get from an API and this is the schema:

[image]

I've connected the "active" property with the `checked` attribute of a Switch MUI button, so naturally, when calling the API I have some users with their switch button already on "true". What I am trying to do is to just make the switch functional, and just be able to click it and change its state, not necessarily doing anything with that.

Here's my toggleType.js:

```
export const TOGGLE = "TOGGLE";
```

Here's my toggleAction.js:

```
import { TOGGLE } from "./toggleType";

const statusToggleAction = () => {
  return {
    type: TOGGLE,
  };
};
export const statusToggle = () => {
  return statusToggleAction();
};
```

Here's my toggleReducer.js:

```
import { TOGGLE } from "./toggleType";

const initialState = {
  status: false,
};

const toggleReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case TOGGLE:
      status: true;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
export default toggleReducer;
```

Everything is under my userContainer.js, like that:

```
const rows = userData.users.map((user) => {
    return {
      id: user.id,
      type: user.type,
      name: user.name,
      email: user.email,
      phone: user.phone,
      active: user.active,
    };
  });
  const columns = [
    { field: "type", headerName: "TYPE", width: 200 },
    { field: "name", headerName: "NAME", width: 150 },
    { field: "email", headerName: "EMAIL", width: 180 },
    { field: "phone", headerName: "TELEPHONE", width: 150 },
    {
      field: "active",
      headerName: "STATUS",
      width: 70,
      sortable: false,
      renderCell: ({ value }) => (
        <Switch checked={value} onChange={statusToggle} />
      ),
    },
  ];

  return userData.loading ? (
    <h2>Loading</h2>
  ) : userData.error ? (
    <h2>{userData.error}</h2>
  ) : (
    <Container maxWidth="lg" style={{ flexGrow: 1, height: "100%" }}>
      <h2>Users</h2>
      <div style={{ height: 600, width: "100%" }}>
        {userData && userData.users && (
          <DataGrid
            rows={rows}
            columns={columns}
            checkboxSelection
            disableSelectionOnClick
          />
        )}
      </div>
    </Container>
  );
```

the switch appears to be not clickable and the state remains unchanged. I just want the switch to be clicked without necessarily editing my data.
[image]

Any ideas are welcome, I "learned" redux like 3 days ago!

Answer (score 0):

Not have much experience with redux but I think you need a store somewhere and the use dispatch to update the state. Something like:

```
const statusToggleAction = () => {
  store.dispatch({type: 'TOGGLE'})
};
```

The store could be something  like this:

```
const store = createStore(toggleReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk))
```

and in the reducer you would need to handle the status change

```
const toggleReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case TOGGLE:      
      return { status: !state.status};
    default:
      return initialState;
  }
};
```

Comment: there's already a store, just not in the files that are referenced. Also, this is what my code looked like before, with the dispatch, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71519184/typeerror-dispatch-is-not-a-function-when-clicking-the-toggle-button/71519360?noredirect=1#comment126407887_71519360 I changed it, so that I don't get the error, but my code's still not working.

Comment: did you update the reducer to return  { status: !state.status} instead of true?